# CSP report-uri does not work

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm using the following PHP script to test CSP policy,

```
<?php
   header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src https:; report-uri /report.php");
   header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'");
?>

<html>
   <body>
        <script src="http://google/abc.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The CSP policy works,

[image]

But the `report-uri` part didn't. The reporting request was never sent and no relevant entry in nginx access logs

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried a fully qualified domain and path?

Comment: @ISMSDEV Tried both IP address and fqdn, but I only edited /etc/hosts to achieve it

Comment: You tried with only the one header being set? Your second one doesn’t have the report uri. Take that line out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Content-Security-Policy standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#csp-header):

> A server SHOULD NOT send more than one HTTP response header field named "Content-Security-Policy" with a given resource representation.

But, you are using multiple Content-Security-Policy headers. The behavior is not defined for this case. But it looks like that the browsers in this case only use the latest header. This means your first header which specifies a `report-uri` gets ignored and only the second header use, which does not specify a `report-uri`.

Comment: Yes that looks like the problem. Missed that initially